# Click function not firing on every click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on this portfolio site of mine
http://miketest.best/

and the top right hamburger `.toggleClass()` doesn't fire immediately on every click. Seems to work but there's some weird delay sometimes that doesn't make it fire/toggle immediately upon each click (if at all)?

If useful this is Wordpress and using it on my custom theme.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.cls').click(function(){
    console.log('fire');
    $('.open').toggleClass('oppenned');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  class="open">
 <span class="cls"></span>
 <span>
        <ul class="sub-menu ">
   <li onclick="slideTo('slide-2')">HOME
   </li>
   <li onclick="slideTo('slide-0')">ABOUT
   </li>
   <li onclick="slideTo('slide-1')">SERVICES
   </li>
   <li onclick="slideTo('slide-3')">PORTFOLIO
   </li>
            <li onclick="slideTo('slide-4')">CONTACT
   </li>
  </ul>
 </span>
 <span class="cls"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Eeek! Attach event handlers in javascript otherwise called functions need to be in the global namespace.

Comment: Mean jQuery(document).ready(function($){}? It's in there... @Roamer-1888

Comment: `<li onclick="slideTo('slide-2')">` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of applying `click` on `.cls` try it on `.open`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('.open').click(function(){
  console.log('fire');
  $('.open').toggleClass('oppenned');
 });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Your trigger class is `.cls`,but in your `DOM` you have don't give any visible content to click.I was added `.cls` to a string `click me` and added that `.cls` class some styling.
**Check out this**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.cls').click(function(){
    console.log('fire');
    $('.open').toggleClass('oppenned');
  });
});
```

```css
.oppenned{
  background:#e3e3e3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  class="open">
    <span class="cls"></span>
    <span>

        <ul class="sub-menu ">
            <li onclick="slideTo('slide-2')">HOME
            </li>
            <li onclick="slideTo('slide-0')">ABOUT
            </li>
            <li onclick="slideTo('slide-1')">SERVICES
            </li>
            <li onclick="slideTo('slide-3')">PORTFOLIO
            </li>
      <li onclick="slideTo('slide-4')">CONTACT
            </li>
        </ul>
    </span>
    <span class="cls">click me</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Providing an answer entirely composed of code without any explanation or reference is simply unacceptable on StackOverflow. Please see the [this meta post for more details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers). You will need to revise your answer to include an explanation of how you're addressing the ops question.

Comment: It's weird I had this exact function as well and didn't work. Was in the jQuery(document).ready(function($)....

  ```
$('.cls').click(function(){
    console.log('fire');
    $('.open').toggleClass('oppenned');
  });

```

Answer (score 1):

you was using click event on a non-visible span tag. That's why the click event is not working. just use any text or any element inside the span tag. Then you will get it visible. when you will on visible element it will work.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.cls').click(function() {
        console.log('fire');
        $(this).parents('.open').stop().toggleClass('oppenned');
    });
});
```

```html
<style type="text/css">
    .oppenned{
      background:#e3e3e3;
    }
</style>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  class="open">
    <span class="cls">something to click me</span>
    <span>
        <ul class="sub-menu ">
            <li onclick="slideTo('slide-2')">HOME</li>
            <li onclick="slideTo('slide-0')">ABOUT</li>
            <li onclick="slideTo('slide-1')">SERVICES</li>
            <li onclick="slideTo('slide-3')">PORTFOLIO</li>
            <li onclick="slideTo('slide-4')">CONTACT</li>
        </ul>
    </span>
    <span class="cls">something to click me</span>
</div>
```